# Angular - Controller with no HTML and broadcasted events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I have a weird situation. I have a controller that I want to control when a dialog opens. I'm using ngDialog in combination with templates and directives. Here is the DialogController code:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('Common').controller('DialogController', DialogController);

    DialogController.$inject = ['$scope', 'ngDialog'];

    function DialogController($scope, ngDialog) {
        $scope.$on('openDialog', open);

        function open(which) {
            ngDialog.open({
                template: which,
                className: 'newproductdialog'
            });
        }
    }

})();
```

This controller has no HTML associated with it - its sole purpose is to open, close, etc the ngDialog.

Here is how I try to trigger the dialog to open (`vm.navigate` is called through ng-click) in HomeController:

```
    function initNav() {
        /**
         * Nav items array.
         * @type {{name: string, id: string, selected: boolean, icon: string}[]}
         */
        vm.navs = [{
            name: 'Home',
            id: 'home',
            selected: true,
            icon: 'ss-home'
        }, {
            name: 'New',
            id: 'create-new-product',
            selected: false,
            icon: 'ss-addfile'
        }];
        /**
         * Color of the navigation elements.
         * @type {string}
         */
        vm.color = '#ea8daf';

        /**
         * Navigation function when clicking a nav item.
         * @param item {object} The $scope.navs object that was clicked.
         */
        vm.navigate = function(item) {
            switch(item.id) {
                case 'create-new-product':
                    ----->$rootScope.$broadcast('openDialog', 'newproduct');
                    break;
            }
        };
    }
```

And the associated HTML for the above method: `<ft-nav items="homeCtrl.navs" onselect="homeCtrl.navigate" color="homeCtrl.color"></ft-nav>`

This doesn't actually work though. I'm wondering if it's because `DialogController` has no associated HTML? Am I doing something wrong with the broadcast event? I know I can use a service and `DialogController` can watch the service, but using $broadcast seems like a better way to go. Any ideas?? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. `DialogController` won't run if it's not specified on a DOM element using the `ngController` directive.

Instead of defining a controller, use a `.run` block.

```
app.run(function ($rootScope, ngDialog) {
  /* ... */
});
```

The code passed to `.run` will run right away without any associated DOM.

Comment: Yeah, lightbulb just went off. Thanks!

Comment: Np, glad to help. Do also keep in mind that you will not have access to `$scope` because scopes are tied to DOM elements. However, you will still have access to `$rootScope` which is the parent of all angular scopes and is tied to the element `ngApp` is used on :)